# MongoDB deployment across cloud and On Premises

Tags: mongodb, aws, redhat, cloud

We are planning to implement MongoDB as a stretch cluster which includes Primary secondary in DC 1, Secondary secondary in DC 2, Arbiter in cloud(DC 3) where DC 1 and DC 2 are on premise servers and DC 3 in cloud

My questions are :

1) Should we need to keep same OS in AWS as our On-premise server or we can keep Amazon Linux also ? 
In our case it is RHEL 7.2 in On premise servers

2) If No, will there be a performance impact if we use different OS between replica nodes ?

3) If yes, Do we need to do patch upgrades as frequent as we do in On Prem servers ?

4) How the failover works here in case of write concern as Majority ?

5) What are the other trade-offs in this approach if any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Should we need to keep same OS in AWS as our On-premise server or we can keep Amazon Linux also ? In our case it is RHEL 7.2 in On premise servers

There is no strict requirement to have the same O/S for all members of a replica set, but in general it is a good idea to have consistent O/S so you have similar configuration and performance tuning across replica set members.

However, since your DC3 (cloud) instance appears to be an arbiter (which only participates in voting) any O/S differences should be irrelevant to performance.

> 2. If No, will there be a performance impact if we use different OS between replica nodes ?

Amazon Linux evolved from RHEL, so isn't an entirely different O/S (for example, like Linux vs Windows). However, there may be different configuration or tuning between Linux distributions. I wouldn't expect dramatically different performance between Linux distros, but this is something you'd have to test with your own use case and workload.

> 3. If yes, Do we need to do patch upgrades as frequent as we do in On Prem servers ?

This is up to your own security policy, but I would expect patch upgrades to be applied similarly for On-Premises versus cloud servers.

> 4. How the failover works here in case of write concern as Majority ?

Assuming you have an equal number of instances in DC1 vs DC2, an arbiter can be useful to ensure a primary can be elected in the event either DC is unreachable. An arbiter cannot acknowledge writes (since it is a voting-only node), so if you have a Primary-Secondary-Arbiter (PSA) configuration you will not be able to acknowledge majority writes if one of your data bearing nodes is unavailable.

I would strongly recommend using PSS (i.e. no arbiter) to support consistent failover with both elections and majority write concern.

> 5. What are the other trade-offs in this approach if any ?

As noted above, arbiters cannot acknowledge write so are not recommendable if you want to support fault tolerance with majority write concern. With a PSA configuration degraded to PsA (one secondary down), you have write availability (since a primary can still be maintained) but no longer have replication or data redundancy (since there is only one data-bearing node writing data).